# Update DataList with textBox input

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, datalist

I have the following textBox -

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server"
 MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServiceMethod="PRETURN" ServicePath="WebService1.asmx"     
 TargetControlID="TextBox1"> </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

When a user types into `TextBox1` this sends a request to `WebService1.asmx` and calls the `PRETURN` service method. So as a user is typing the textBox brings a drop down list of strings that start with the letters the user is typing.

I now have the following DataList -

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="pTextBox" >

<ItemTemplate>

<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxPN" runat="server"  Checked='false' OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxPN_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
<asp:TextBox ID="profileTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>'></asp:TextBox>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Where on `Page_Load` -

```
WebService1 ws = new WebService1();
pTextBox.DataSource = ws.Method();
pTextBox.DataBind();
```

My problem is I want to combine the functionality of the textBox with the DataList. So that when a user types into the textBox, instead of the textBox having a dropdown list, the rows in the DataList are updated. So for instance, if Text in the `profileTextBox` did not contain the prefix text in TextBox1 when the user was typing, it would disappear. Leaving the user with a list of rows relevant to their search. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm confused... are you saying the user can only type in items that are defined within the datalist control?

Comment: I perhaps need to re-word my question, however essentially, the datalist needs a search filter through a textbox, so when the user types a letter only profileTextBox that contain strings that start with that letter are shown. The autocomplete textBox with web service method is perhaps irrelevant I just need a filter for the datalist can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Others have done something similar to the GridView control, using JQuery to show/hide rows depending on the filter criteria.  One solution, which should be easily adaptable to the DataList, is available [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-jquery-to-manipulate-and-filter-data/).

Comment: the link seems to be broken?

Comment: Try now.  Copy and paste failed last time :-)